# what does this quote mean? “Be as intentional with what you say yes to as what you say no to.” ~Robyn Conley Downs

Tags: meaning

What does this quote mean?

> “Be as intentional with what you say yes to as what you say no to.”
>                           ~Robyn Conley Downs

Comment: Always be serious about the things you say.

Answer (score 1):

To "be intentional" means to do things with intention, not inadvertently, by habit or unconscious drift.
 You may be "intentional" about avoiding risky behavior, for example. That is a negative choice, something you "say no to".
 You may allow yourself to spend an hour talking idly to your neighbor. That could be called a positive choice, something you "say yes to", but not what you intended to do. Maybe if you were intentional about it, you would not spend quite as much time.